# How to preserve line formatting while echoing out \r\n from a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array that is created dynamically and consists of line breaks at "\r\n". I want to replace the values of this array randomly while making sure "\r\n" is not replaced and it is written out as a line break in its exact position.

```
<script ="javascript">
    var r = <?php echo json_encode($t, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>; // getting random nu.
    //document.write(randomy);
    var here = <?php echo json_encode($ther, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
    var jtotal = <?php echo json_encode($total, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
    var count = 0;

    for (var b = 0; b < jtotal; b++) {
        if ((b == r) && (here[b] == "\r\n")) {
            document.write('\n');
        }
        else if (b == r) {
            count = count + 1;
            document.write("____(" + count + ")____");
            r = r + 7;
        }
        else {
            document.write(here[b] + " ");
        }
    }
</script>
</pre>
```

Can anyone tell me what went wrong here?

`jtotal` is the size of the array. `r` is the random number, `r+3` will remove every third word from the random number. Everything is fine but when the random value gets to "\n\r", the code breaks down. I want to make sure "\n\r" is never replaced and always outputs a line break.

Comment: Mind to explain your code? what is `jtotal` ? what `r` means? why are you doing `r=r+3` ? why are you checking if `b==r` ?

Comment: and please write what result you expect. count = count+1; can be written as count++;

Comment: jtotal is the size of the array. r is the random number, r+3, will remove  every third word from the random number. Everything is fine but when the random value gets to "\n\r" , the code breaks down. I want to make sure "\n\r" is never replaced and always outputs a line break.

Comment: Can you please update your question with these details.  Also, perhaps add the PHP tag, or remove the PHP portion of your code.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan - I put more details - including PHP Tags

Comment: as i see in your code `r` and ` jTotal` are json object and are sure? your loop condition is correct

Comment: Yes the loop is correct ..